# Joining two Tables with matching two values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One is `user`. `user` has two columns.

- `user_id`
- `user_name`

The other table is `product`. `product` has two columns.

- `product_type`
- `seller_id`

`seller_id` is a foreign key of `user.user_id`.

An example of `product_type` is "laptop". 
I want to list all the names of users who are selling laptops. 
(SQL Query)

Comment: The only thing you need is to upbuild the task's words in correct order and form - you need to `SELECT user.user_name FROM user, products WHERE products.seller_id = user.user_id AND products.product_type = 'laptop'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_name FROM user u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product p
                WHERE product_type = 'laptop'
                AND p.seller_id = u.user_id)
```